# Facebook Javascript API fan_count

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I am new to Javascript and am try to follow the Facebook steps to display fan_count (likes) on my webpage. I have done the following but for the life of me can't work out how the count is displayed.

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : '231179987472162',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v3.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<script>
      FB.api(
        '/cityviewshopping',
        'GET',
        {"fields":"fan_count"},
        function(response) {
        // Insert your code here
        }
      );
</script>
```

Comment: Probably you forgot to wrap `FB.api(...)` into <script> tag. And you have to replace "_// Insert your code here_" with a code that will insert number from the response into your page. For example with jQuery `$(body).append(reponse.fan_count)`.

Comment: there is a html tag in the middle of javascript...also, you need to do that server side because you need at least an app access token (and those cannot be hardcoded in client code). also, you need to cache the result, so you don´t hit the facebook api with every single user who visits your page.

Comment: also, FB.api can only be called AFTER FB.init. you have to init the js sdk before using it.

Comment: I have added the script tags but have no idea how to call the result.

Comment: Any ideas what I would input in (// insert your code here) to call the result?